# Post wordpress post on facebook using SDK

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, post, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to post wordpress post on facebook. I have used javascript SDK  of facebook and used save_post hook to get the title and content of post. But, the problem is the save_post is in php and I have to use the variables in javascript and I am not able to do it. And I even doubt what I am doing is right.

Here is my js code

```
function streamPublish(name, description, hrefTitle, hrefLink, userPrompt)
{
            showLoader(true);
            FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'stream.publish',
                message: '',
                attachment: {
                    name: name,
                    caption: '',
                    description: (description),
                    href: hrefLink
                },
                action_links: [
                    { text: hrefTitle, href: hrefLink }
                ],
                user_prompt_message: userPrompt
            },
            function(response) {
                showLoader(false);
            });

        }
        function showStream(){
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {

            var fbpost = document.getElementById('posttofb').val();
            alert(fbpost);

            streamPublish(response.name, 'title', 'hrefTitle', 'http://thinkdiff.net', "Share thinkdiff.net");

            });
        }
```

and my php code

```
add_action('save_post','save_post_callback');
function save_post_callback($post_id)
{
global $post; 
if ($post->post_type != 'post')
{
    return;
}
else
{
echo"122222222222222";
?>

<div id="posttofb">
<?php
$title=$post->post_title;
?>
</div> 

<?php
echo $post->post_content;
//echo $post->the_title();
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will execute your javascript after id posttofb is written.

Try something like:

```
<div id="posttofb">
<?php
$title=$post->post_title;
?>
</div> 
<script>
$(function() { //document.Ready
showStream();
});
</script>
```

or in this case only (change your showStream to showStream(title)):

```
<script>
$(function() { //document.Ready
showStream(<?=$post->post_title?>);
});
</script>
```